# Find the Degree matrix $D$ using the Adjacency matrix $A$ and (half of) the coordinates of a graph.

Tags: graph-laplacian, barycentric-coordinates

Say, we have a graph $G$ with 6 points of which 3 are given.
The coordinates of the other 3 points are unknown at this point.
I got the (full) adjacency matrix and the 3 coordinates.

How do I calculate the Degree matrix $D$ at this point?

This may be a barycenter problem but since I’m new to that topic, I can’t see how to calculate the matrix $D$.

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd need the coordinates in order to compute the degree matrix. The degree of a vertex $v$ is equal to the sum along the row $v$ in the adjacency matrix. You could also take the trace of $A^2$. Could you elaborate on your precise problem?